# How to shorten a multi dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array that looks like this

```
Array
(
    [11] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [type] => OPT 
                    [panel] => 1
                    [loop] => 1
                    [number] => 1
                    [zone] =>  1  
                    [value] => 38  
                )

        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [type] => OPT 
                    [panel] => 1
                    [loop] => 2
                    [number] => 1
                    [zone] => 19  
                    [value] => 40  
                )

        )

)
```

I want to delete the first dimension so that it looks like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
         (
                [type] => OPT 
                [panel] => 1
                [loop] => 1
                [number] => 1
                [zone] =>  1  
                [value] => 38  
         )

    [1] => Array
        (
                [type] => OPT 
                [panel] => 1
                [loop] => 2
                [number] => 1
                [zone] => 19  
                [value] => 40  
        )

)
```

How do I do that?
Sorry but I have to put in some test or the compiler won't let me post the code.

Comment: A foreach loop would work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php) as

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge',$your_array);
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/401434)

Comment: Simpel and smooth. Thanks!

Comment: You are Welcome.Glad it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$short = array();

foreach($long as $k=>$v) {
  $short[] = $array[$k][0];
}

var_dump($short);
```

provided that you have only one element in 2nd level

Comment: You might want to do `$short[] = $v;` That way you don't have to worry about how many elements there are.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets no its not possible if value `$v` is again multdimensional array. it will work if `$v` is an associative array

Comment: yea true, you need two foreachloops in it to get that. [example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3e7d3741c251d0d1262d2e6430714122000534a2) but if you modify your answer to correspond to that, it's more flexible to op's design and you won't get an array index exception if there is an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

Just go through each sub array and [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) the arrays with your `$result` together, e.g.

```
<?php

    $result = [];

    foreach($arr as $v)
        $result = array_merge($result, $v);

    print_r($result);

?>
```

[<kbd>**Demo**</kbd>](https://eval.in/401427)